# Find users / roles that have a certain permission in Sonatype Nexus Repository 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

In Sonatypes Nexus Repository 3, is there a way to see which users/roles imply a certain permission?

Answer (score 0):

In NXRM3 (and NXRM2), Users are given 1 to many Roles which are made up of 1 to many Privileges.  The privileges define what areas of the site you can access and what you can do.

If you edit the respective User, you can see what Roles they have.
If you subsequently edit the respective Role, you can see what Privileges they have.
Admittedly, some of the privileges are more clear than others.  nx-analytics-all for example gives access to the analytics section.  One common confusion is the repository view vs admin permissions.  The former gives permission to browse and access components while the latter gives access to administrate the repositories (empty cache, set timeouts, change the source URL).

If unclear about a specific privilege, a good source is the Sonatype user group: https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/nexus-users
Licensed customers are welcome to contact support or their customer representative.

Reference: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Roles

Comment: I'm aware that the "effective privileges" of a user can be deduced by navigating the role-tree for that user, but this is a pita in nexus 3. In nexus 2, there was a preview for the effective privileges of a user, which made it easier to hunt down configuration problems.

Comment: @Florian Ah I think I better understand your question.  As far as I know there's no such document outlining what every privilege does.  This is something the Sonatype Customer Education team is aware of and I believe working on soon if not already.  Perhaps there will be a better answer soon.